# how to do i prove this simple probabilty result

Tags: probability

I want to prove the estimate

\begin{equation*}
P(|A+B|>c)\leq P(|A|>c/2)+P(|B|>c/2), 
\end{equation*}

where $A$ and $B$ are random variables and $c>0$. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the following: If $|A|\leq c/2$ and $|B|\leq c/2$, then $|A+B|\leq c$. It might be useful to negate this statement and then use the subadditivity of the probability measure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it directly follows from the union bound.